# Applying a pose on a rig so that it will appear in object mode

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

I'm working on a scene with some rigs, with the intentions of setting them up just so I could hand paint them later (kind of like that wooden figurine thing). Anyway, there are multiple models I've downloaded form mixamo, and I want to set each one with a certain pose.

I edit the pose in *Pose* mode, but in order to switch between characters, I need to tab out back to object mode, and every time I do so, my model resets back to its original T-Pose.

I already created a pose library for each model (by the way, how do I apply changes to an already created pose?), so right now the only thing to do is just keep them all in place.

I'm not that new to blender but all I ever did was modeling and sculpting.

Comment: Have you checked whether the T-pose is actually a key-framed pose? Are there any key frames in the timeline or is there an action in the Action Editor?

Comment: Object mode should just display whatever you have in pose mode, so I would ask the same as @Blunder. It could be that you made a pose on already existing keyframes/animation without keyframing that pose, hence anytime you switch modes it goes back to what is actually keyframed.

Comment: Otherwise, please upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check what's going on.